# Find dynamically added control in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, controls, dynamic-controls

I've created a new tabpage and also added a richtextbox to it:

```
Private Sub AddTab(ByVal ctrl As TabControl, _
                              ByVal text As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New AddTabDelegate(AddressOf AddTab), _
                  New Object() {ctrl, text})
        Return
    End If

    Dim NewTab As New TabPage
    NewTab.Name = "OutputTab" & outputs.Item(outputs.Count - 1)
    NewTab.Text = "Domain"
    Dim NewTextbox As New RichTextBox
    NewTextbox.Name = "OutputTextbox" & outputs.Item(outputs.Count - 1)

    ctrl.Controls.Add(NewTab)
    NewTab.Controls.Add(NewTextbox)
End Sub
```

Now I try to access the richtextbox somewhere else in the code:

```
Dim NewTextbox As RichTextBox
NewTextbox = Me.Controls.Item("OutputTextbox" & current_output)
debug.print(NewTextbox.name)
```

I get the following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in program.exe
```

I know the name is rigth cause I have printed the name in the create method and I have printed the name string in the code where I try to access it.

So by the looks of it it seems `.Item()` is not the right way to access the control.

So how to access to dynamically created control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the dynamic control to a container by name `ctrl` and later looking for it in the form container. You can search recursively using `Me.FindControl()` but in your case, since you know the container that has the `RichTextBox`, it would be more efficient to do something as shown below.

Try

```
Dim NewTextbox As RichTextBox
Dim NewTab as TabPage
NewTab = ctrl.Controls.Item("OutputTab" & current_output)
NewTextbox = newTab.Controls.Item("OutputTextbox" & current_output)

debug.print(NewTextbox.name)
```